# Erlang and the records

Tags: erlang, record

What is wrong in this code?
I was expected `"titi"` in `person.name` but I still have `"toto"`!
More explicitly, how to modify a record in a function?

```
init1()->
    S=#person{name="toto"},   %record creation and field setting
    fct(S),
    io:format("~s~n",[S#person.name]).

fct(R)->
    R#person{name="titi"}.    %record updating
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Bertaud, I think you are getting ahead of yourself a bit.  You really need to understand the basics of immutability before you write any more code.  (i.e. "variables" do not vary : you can only assign a value to them once.)  I suggest you read the free online guide "Learn You Some Erlang For Great Good", at http://learnyousomeerlang.com/.  The section that covers the basics of variables is http://learnyousomeerlang.com/starting-out-for-real#invariable-variables.

Answer (score 10):

You need to get a result of fct():

```
init1()->
    S=#person{name="toto"},   %record creation and field setting
    S2 = fct(S),   % Get updated record
    io:format("~s~n",[S2#person.name]).

fct(R)->
    R#person{name="titi"}.    %record updating
```

Comment: Is it possible to declare a global record ?

Comment: @Bertaud, global variables are against the design principles of Erlang. Even if the variable is global, you cannot modify it because of immutability of variables in Erlang. If you still want to use you can store the record in process dictionary using put and get (can only be accessed by the process, but eliminates the need to pass the data around the functions) or use ets tables.

Comment: my question wasn't correctly formulated because my example returns the record. If the function modify the record, compute and retun a value, how to read the modified record in the caller ?

Comment: The function can not update S as all variables, including records, are immutable. So like in the example hdima gave you he took the modified record returned and assigned it to the S2 variable.

Comment: You need to capture the modified record in a different variable as in the code by @hdima

Comment: Please ignore the advice about process dictionaries.  Just learn to deal Erlang as if they didn't exist.

Answer (score 2):

It is impossible to stress too much that all data in Erlang is immutable. So to do something like in your original question you need to modify it like @hdima did. The record is not updated but rewritten. In the same way there is no global data in Erlang, all data belongs to a process. This is even true of ETS tables as they basically behave like a process, albeit a built-in one without explicit communication.

So if you use the process dictionary or an ETS table the **data** itself can never be updated, only the dictionary/table. This means that to modify some data in the dictionary/table you basically have to:

1. "Read" the data
2. Update the data making new data
3. "Write" the new back into the dictionary/table

Without writing the new data back into the dictionary/table it will be lost, as your new data was.

Answer (score 0):

Within fct(), you're not mutating the record, but you're returning a new value for the record, which needs to be used further. If you're calling fct(S), without handling the return value, then you'll lose that new value ("titi").